# jQuery Cycle plugin: centering background images when browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow using the jQuery Cycle plugin, changing divs with a background image (the images are very wide and if the browser is smaller, they should be centered and cut off).

```
<div class="banner_images">
    <div style="background-image:url(banners/1.jpg)"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(banners/2.jpg)"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(banners/3.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

Before Cycle is applied, the page behaves exactly as intended when the browser window is resized: http://30daysoffalafel.com/test/index-nojs.html

After Cycle is applied, when the browser is resized the background image doesn't stay centered. Refreshing the browser fixes the problem.
http://30daysoffalafel.com/test/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.banner_images').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            pager: '.banner_controls div'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas for how to change the behavior so that the image background centers on browser resize the same way after cycle is applied? I would prefer not to add js to refresh on window resize.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using `$(window).on('resize', function() { /*...*/ });`?

Comment: Actually, I think you might be using the old version of cycle? Try [cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/), which seems to support responsive slideshows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.banner_images').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    pager: '.banner_controls div',
    fit: 1,
    width: '100%',
    slideResize: true,
    containerResize: false
});
```